# Is it possible to review the 'payload' of a signed transaction string before posting it?

Tags: transactions

Some wallet apps let you generate a signed transaction if you do not have access to the internet on a device or if you want to have it ready to send at a later time.

Is it possible to decode that string so that you can at least verify the recipient address as well as the amount to be sent to ensure there are no typos or bugs in the wallet app before it's posted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `ethereumjs-tx` node module to get the transaction.

```
const ethTx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const tx = new ethTx(<raw tx string>); // This object contains all the tx details
console.log(tx.to.toString('hex'));
console.log(tx.value.toString('hex'))
```

You can find all the data regarding the transaction from the `tx` object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `rlpdump` tool from go-ethereum: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/cmd/rlpdump

Specifically, `rlpdump --hex <tx bytes encoded in hex>` is very useful. Though you may then need to use python or similar (`int('deadbeef', 16)`) to decode the hex values